# Toad for Oracle Query formatter does not format query having "?"

Tags: oracle, toad

I having trouble in formatting a query having `"?"` in right hand side of `where` condition.

Example

```
Select * 
 From mytable 
 Where column_name = ?
```

I know question mark "?" is not valid in query. 
It gives `ORA-00911: invalid character`

But Is there any way to bypass this check for question mark in toad and query get formatted?

Note: I am using toad 10.6

Comment: Why do you want to run a query in TOAD which has invalid syntax?

Comment: @APC I don't want to run that query as it is.It is quite difficult to understand and make changes to query displaying in single line. I just want to format the query so I can easily substitute the values. I am getting the query from console where it is in single line.

Comment: I would use a regular text editor, such as TextPad or VIM, to format the query.  Then do whatever you wnat with it in TOAD.  It's about using the appropriate tool for the job.

Comment: Replace the "?" with something else, perhaps bind variable syntax and toad should happily format it.

Comment: @Ollie that is the alternative way of doing that.

Comment: To All, Mentioned query get formatted in toad 9.5 problem is with the 10.6 may be some formatting option or something.